# Can I sign not XML with XAdES?

Tags: xml, digital-signature

I can find only examples where I can sign XML file using [XAdES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAdES) (XML Advanced Electronic Signatures ). What if I want to sign a base64 string? It looks like requirement in the task I get.

Comment: Yes, you can sign any external data with XMLDSig (and XAdES). I don't know what libraries or classes support this besides our SecureBlackbox, though (our product can do this).

Comment: As @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp says you can sign any external data with XMLDsig, however this case you can only generate detached signature form nor enveloping neither enveloped , about the libraries you can use I use apache XMLSecurity to do so: http://santuario.apache.org/

Comment: @albciff "however this case you can only generate detached signature form nor enveloping neither enveloped"... eh, come again? I cannot parse that sentence.

Comment: @owlstead sorry my english is not so good and I also said the things wrong :(... the thing I was trying to say: To sign base64 string in XML signatures it's only possible using detached or enveloping  form, if you use enveloped the signature must be performed over XML document not on base64 string.

Comment: @albciff thanks for the clarification, much more clear now

Comment: @albciff you two comments differ a bit. Is only detached possible or detached and enveloping?

Comment: @KrzysztofMorcinek yes I know, In the second comment I try to explain that my first comment was wrong... in resume the second is the good one: to sign base64 string in XML signatures you can use detached and enveloping form.